# Wrong variable posts via mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table `gquestions` with columns `id`,`answer`,`date`. I'm trying to update string in table with this HTML form and PHP queries:

**HTML**

```
<form action="/reply" method="post">
    <textarea name="answer"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Reply">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
$p_answer = $_POST["answer"];
$time = time();
mysql_query("UPDATE gquestions SET answer='$p_answer' AND date='$time' WHERE id='1'");
echo "UPDATE gquestions SET answer='$p_answer' AND date='$time' WHERE id='1'";
```

Okay, in form I'm typing in textarea **Test** and clicking Reply and get this result in page:

`UPDATE gquestions SET answer='Test' AND date='1490982467' id='1'`

but in table I get **0** instead of **Test** in `answer` column. Why I'm getting 0 in my column?

Comment: column type is different, maybe int change it to varchar or text for answer column

Comment: What's the table definition?

Comment: @vSugumar I've already checked that before, it was VARCHAR, I've changed it to TEXT, no result

Comment: @David Definition is 0

Comment: @MrJo: Then I guess your problem is that you don't have an actual database table.  You just have an integer.  If you want to store data in a table, you need to create a table.

Comment: Change the "AND" in your query to a comma. AND is a logical operator.

Comment: @David, oh no, I didn't mean that, I already have a table `gquestions`, but column's definition is `0`

Comment: @kainaw ohhh maaan, thats suppa, I forgot about that! Let's post it as a reply

Comment: @downvoter: why?

Comment: @MrJo: `"@downvoter: why?"` - Because you're being asked to share your table definition, and you're not sharing it.  Instead, you're just repeating the original problem that the data being inserted is a `0`.  The Stack Overflow community is requesting additional information in order to help you.  If you won't provide that information, the chances of solving the problem drop dramatically.  If you just want us to trust you that the table/code/etc. are correct, then the question becomes moot.  "Trust me, it's right, I just need to know why it isn't working" is fundamentally unanswerable.

Comment: @David I just didn't understand what did you mean with "table definition", I don't know what is it

Comment: Additionally, what is the value in the column *before* you perform the `UPDATE`?  Your code is SQL-injectable and you're not checking for errors, so how have you confirmed that the `UPDATE` succeeds *at all*?

Comment: @David I've simplified code, cutted security for simplicity. Original value was just empty. And I've already solved the problem.

Comment: @MrJo: Table definition: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html

Comment: @David Please, remove downvote, I just didn't know what is it

Comment: @MrJo: `"cutted security for simplicity"` - So you've *entirely changed how you interact with the database* just for the purposes of the question?  If the code in the question is vastly different from the code causing the problem, *how can anybody reliably answer*?  It's great that you've solved the problem, it really is, but that seems like more of a random coincidence than anything.

Comment: @MrJo: `"Please, remove downvote"` - Sorry, no.  The question is admittedly full of misinformation and is unlikely to be of any use to anybody else.  I'm genuinely glad you've solved the problem, so don't take this the wrong way.  But this is exactly what the voting system is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
UPDATE gquestions SET answer='$p_answer' AND date='$time' WHERE id='1'
```

To

```
UPDATE gquestions SET answer='$p_answer', date='$time' WHERE id='1'
```

Answer (score 1):

column type is different, maybe int change it to varchar or text for answer column.

your query is wrong

```
"UPDATE gquestions SET answer='$p_answer' AND date='$time' WHERE id='1'"
```

should be  there shouldn't and

```
"UPDATE gquestions SET answer='$p_answer',date='$time' WHERE id='1'"
```

Answer (score 0):

update your code

```
UPDATE gquestions SET answer='Test' AND date='1490982467' id='1'
```

to

```
UPDATE gquestions SET answer='Test' , date='1490982467' id='1'
```

this is common format

```
  UPDATE table_name
  SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
  WHERE condition;
```